# Should I open and close sockets per transaction?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, client-server

I have an async server running a slightly modified version of this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx). This only allows one client to join at a time.

My question is, is it okay for me to open and close the socket for every transaction (it uses TCP)? If I allow multiple clients to join (by modifying the code listen for more clients), it seems that some of the messages are cross-wiring. For example, if I try and download a file from the server from two clients, whichever client started last gets the file and the first one times out. Or if I start sending some data from one client, then start from another client, the server received a mix of both.

Since my program doesn't require high performance (like a game might), are there any issues with opening/closing a socket per transaction or is there a better way of handling multiple clients?

Edit - I forgot to mention that the listener itself would remain open throughout the lifetime, but each client would open and close a new socket for the transaction itself. In the code in the MSDN link, the variable is "handler".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are overheads in opening and closing sockets, so the short answer is no (on the listening side). That is just best practice though so if you are not worried about this then use whatever works.

When it comes to the client the socket usage really depends on how frequently you plan to send data. If infrequently then opening a socket for a short period is probably the norm. If you are noticing any sort of 'cross-talk' this is most likely due to an error in your code. For some references checkout the TcpClient and TcpListener classes on MSDN.

Comment: Sockets (for listening) are generally left open for the lifetime of the application, e.g. for HTTP that is a TCP socket on port 80. Each client that connects essentially just exists in its own 'session'.

Comment: I believe he leaves the listening socket opened, if I did not understand the question wrong, he is talking about opening and closing the client sockets

Comment: @HanletEscaño - Yeap, I may have misunderstood the OP. If like you say this is a client related problem there is probably not enough information in the original post to know what might be causing a problem.

Comment: I may also have miunderstood the question LOL, not sure which socket he is talking about.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer there. I did mean leaving the listener open throughout the app, but keep opening and closing new client sockets (in the MSDN code, it's the variable called "handler").

Comment: @MarcF - Thanks, I think I should be fine but I'll look at the TcpListener class. I think my requests will be relatively infrequent (few transactions a second every few minutes).